# How would you write a query that replaces multipe ids in a string with related codes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `courseassociation` with a `varchar` column `formula`. This column contains a string with a boolean formatted string like '123 and (586 or 309)'. This example has three `course_id`s in it, but a formatted string may have 1 to n `course_id`s in it, along with the words 'and' and/or 'or', or parenthesis.

I also have a table `course` that contains a column for `course_id` as `int` and a second column for `course_identifier varchar(20)`.

The inventory_course table has a lot or rows in it, but the records that are specific to this example are:

| course_id | course_identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Alpha |
| 586 | Beta |
| 309 | Gama |

I'm looking to write a query that will:

1. This query will be run on a SQL Server database with compatibility level 2016 (130)
2. I have no control over the fact that the formula is store as a string and has to be converted from using ids to using identifiers.

This is the task at hand:

1. Use both tables `courseassociation` and `inventory_course`
2. The first column in the result should be `courseassociation.formula`
3. The second column will be an updated version of format named `converted_formula`, where each numeric value in formula is replace with the `course_identifier` value from `course`.
4. I don't want to create any tables or temp tables in the process. This should all be done in memory. CTEs are fine.
5. The string in the formula field is dynamic and can contain any number of `course_id` references
6. The query needs to identify which parts of the formula value are `course_id` and then replace the `course_id` with the `course_identifier`. Any non numeric chars should be copied to the `converted_formula` value.
7. Consecutive numbers are treated as one number.
8. Here are some examples of what the results should look like

   | formula | converted_formula |
   | --- | --- |
   | 123 and (586 or 309) | Alpha and (Beta or Gama) |
   | 586 OR 309 | Beta OR Gama |

This is what I was able to come up with. I'm open to improvements or alternative way of accomplishing this. I had to add spaces before an after the parenthesis, but that's OK for what I need.

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(ica.formula, ')', ' )'), '(', '( ') formula,
        CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS updated_formula,
        CAST(replace(replace(ica.formula, ')', ' )'), '(', '( ') + ' ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS remaining_formula
    FROM 
        inventory_courseassociation ica
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.formula,
        CAST(updated_formula + CASE
                                   WHEN part NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                                     THEN COALESCE((SELECT ic.course_identifier FROM inventory_course ic WHERE ic.course_id = CAST(part AS INT)), part)
                                   ELSE part END as varchar(max)) + ' ',
           cast( STUFF(remaining_formula, 1, CHARINDEX(part, remaining_formula) + LEN(part) - 1, '') as varchar(max))
    FROM RecursiveCTE c
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(LTRIM(remaining_formula), CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(remaining_formula)) - 1) AS part) AS ca
    WHERE LEN(remaining_formula) > 0
)

SELECT formula, updated_formula
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE LEN(remaining_formula) = 0;
```

Comment: Can you use a cursor? Can you assume an upper limit on the number of replacements?

Comment: To use a cursor, I think I would need to keep track of two variables, one for the start of the number then one for the end of the number. After that I would have to use substring. And, maybe need a function or stored procedure. 
Is there a way to use a cursor that would simplify the query or make it so that it is not dependent on white spaces as delimiters?

Comment: The number of replacements will most likely not exceed 15.

Comment: I think the key would be to make sure the longest values get replacement applied first. A recursive approach could still work too.

Answer (score 2):

See example. Split `formula` to `words`, then try associate `words` with `course_id` and put the words back together, keeping the order.
During the discussion, we received several variants of the request. They all implement the same algorithm. Differences in the availability of some tools in the DBMS version used.

1. PostgreSql 15.0
2. SQL Server 2019-2022
3. SQL Server 2016-2022
4. SQL Server 2014-2022

```
with words as (
select id,formula
  ,row_number()over(partition by ca.id order by (select null)) rn
  ,word
from courseassociation ca
,regexp_split_to_table(replace(replace(formula,'(', ' ( '),')',' ) '),'\s+') as word
where length(word)>0
)
,cte as(
select *
from words w
left join course c on trim(w.word)=cast(c.course_id as varchar)
)
select id,min(formula) formula
  ,string_agg(coalesce(course_identifier,word),' ' order by rn) newFormula 
from cte
group by id
order by id
```

Thanks [@T N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n) for the comment. He pointed out that an answer was needed for SQL Server and provided an answer option for SQL Server. I hope your version of SQL Server supports the string_split and string_agg functions (compatibility level 2016 (130)).

```
-- version for SQL Server from T N
with words as (
  select id,formula
    ,s.ordinal as rn
    ,s.value as word
  from courseassociation ca
  cross apply string_split(replace(replace(ca.formula,'(', ' ( '),')',' ) '), ' ', 1) s
  where len(s.value) > 0
)
,cte as(
  select *
  from words w
  left join course c on trim(w.word)=cast(c.course_id as varchar)
)
select id,min(formula) formula
  ,string_agg(coalesce(course_identifier,word),' ') within group(order by rn) newFormula 
from cte
group by id
order by id
```

Version for SQL Server 2016. `string_agg` changed by recursive query. And string_split `enable_ordinal` option changed to `row_number()`

```
with words as (
select id,formula
  ,row_number()over(partition by id order by (select null)) as rn
  ,value as word
  ,count(*)over(partition by id) maxWordNum
from courseassociation ca
cross apply string_split(replace(replace(formula,'(', ' ( '),')',' ) '),' ') as w
)
,cte as(
select *
from words w
left join course c on w.word=cast(c.course_id as varchar)
)
,r as(
select id,rn,coalesce(course_identifier,word) as newFormula
  ,formula,maxWordNum
from cte where rn=1
  union all
select r.id,r.rn+1
  ,concat(r.newformula,' ',coalesce(course_identifier,cte.word)) as newFormula
  ,r.formula,r.maxWordNum
from r inner join cte on cte.id=r.id and cte.rn=(r.rn+1)
)
select id,formula,newFormula 
from r 
where rn=maxWordNum
order by id;
```

Simplest version (only recursions). Tested on SQL Server 2014 - 2022.
There `string_agg` replaced by recursive query and `string_split` replaced by recursive query.

```
with formdelim as (select id,replace(replace(formula,'(', ' ( '),')',' ) ') as formula
  from courseassociation
)
,words as ( -- split formula
select id,formula,1 as rn
  ,cast(case when charindex(' ',formula)>0 then 
     substring(formula,1,charindex(' ',formula)-1)
   else formula 
   end as varchar(1000)) word
  ,case when charindex(' ',formula)>0 then 
     substring(formula,charindex(' ',formula)+1,1000)
   else cast(formula as varchar(1000))
   end rest
from formdelim ca
union all
select id,formula,rn+1 as rn
  ,case when charindex(' ',rest)>0 then 
     substring(rest,1,charindex(' ',rest)-1)
   else cast(rest as varchar(1000))
   end word
  ,case when charindex(' ',rest)>0 then 
     substring(rest,charindex(' ',rest)+1,1000)
   else cast('' as varchar(1000))
   end rest
from words where len(rest)>0 -- and rn<20  -- debug control
)
,cte as( -- join with course
select *
  ,count(*)over(partition by id)maxWordNum
from words w
left join course c on w.word=cast(c.course_id as varchar)
)
,r as(-- aggregate back
select id,1 wn,rn,cast(concat(coalesce(course_identifier,word),' ') as varchar(1000)) as newFormula
  ,formula ,maxWordNum
from cte where rn=1
  union all
select r.id,wn+1,r.rn+1
  ,cast(concat(r.newformula,' ',coalesce(course_identifier,cte.word)) as varchar(1000)) as newFormula
  ,r.formula ,r.maxWordNum
from r inner join cte on cte.id=r.id and cte.rn=(r.rn+1)
)
select id,formula,newFormula 
from r 
where rn=maxWordNum
order by id,rn;
```

With test data

```
create table course (course_id int, course_identifier varchar(30));
insert into course values
 (123,'Alpha')
,(586,'Beta')
,(309,'Gama')
;
create table courseassociation (id int,formula varchar(100));
insert into courseassociation values
 (100,'123 and (586 or 309)')
,(101,'586 OR 309')
,(102,'586 AND 587')
;
```

output is

| id | formula | newFormula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | Alpha and ( Beta or Gama ) |
| 101 | 586 OR 309 | Beta OR Gama |
| 102 | 586 AND 587 | Beta AND 587 |

Intermediate result of cte

| id | formula | rn | word | course_id | course_identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 1 | 123 | 123 | Alpha |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 2 | and | null | null |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 3 | ( | null | null |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 4 | 586 | 586 | Beta |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 5 | or | null | null |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 6 | 309 | 309 | Gama |
| 100 | 123 and (586 or 309) | 7 | ) | null | null |
| 101 | 586 OR 309 | 1 | 586 | 586 | Beta |
| 101 | 586 OR 309 | 2 | OR | null | null |
| 101 | 586 OR 309 | 3 | 309 | 309 | Gama |
| 102 | 586 AND 587 | 1 | 586 | 586 | Beta |
| 102 | 586 AND 587 | 2 | AND | null | null |
| 102 | 586 AND 587 | 3 | 587 | null | null |

Comment: I think this is the better approach, as it doesn't need a CTE and matches on whole words. (The latter avoids false match substitutions for ID combos like "12", 123", "4123".) However, this question is tagged as SQL Server and your solution appears to be postgres. I took the liberty of converting the logic for SQL Server that I've coded up in **[SQL Server 2022 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5OynEHM7)** and **[SQL Server 2017 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qwj-LKV5)**. Microsoft only added `string_split()` and `string_agg()` a few years back, so older versions need to use increasingly complex hacks.

Comment: Feel free to incorporate the converted code into you answer if you like.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive comment. I will add your answer to my answer.

Comment: I should be able to convert the string_agg() call to FOR XML PATH. Let me play around with this. I'm on compatibility level 2016 (130)

Comment: @SandyDeLeon - Here is a **[SQL Server 2016 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kbLeQvfr)** that uses the *FOR XML* hack for string aggregation. Because FOR XML does not work with *group by*, it was necessary to combine the steps into a single *cross apply* block. I also dropped the *trim()* in the join condition, because I do not think it was necessary. (For earlier SQL Server versions, the lack of JSON support would mean we would need yet another substitute for an ordered string_split(). Luckily, it appears you don't need that.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could continue this chain up to about 32 times although it might also be horribly inefficient. A loop/cursor might be the best solution though. As a last resort you could do a CLR aggregate:

```
with matches as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ca.formula order by course_id desc) as rn
    from courseassociation as ca inner join
         inventory_course as ic on ca.formula like '%' + course_id + '%'
)
select formula15
from matches m0 cross apply
    (select replace(formula, coalesce(max(course_id), ''), coalesce(max(course_identifier), '')) as formula1
     from matches m
     where m.formula = m0.formula and m.rn = 1) as r1 cross apply
    (select replace(formula1, coalesce(max(course_id), ''), coalesce(max(course_identifier), '')) as formula2
     from matches m
     where m.formula = m0.formula and m.rn = 2) as r2 cross apply ...
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, the issue will be that when the formula is something like '231 AND 5867' the CTE will be matching all partial course_ids like 1, 2, 3, ..., 23, 31, ..., 586, 867, etc.. I just ran it. This formula just came back with over 30 matches '(35930) AND (1099) AND (35932) AND (19292) AND (4799)'. I'm going to play around with this idea a bit

Comment: Here we go. This might work. 
'%[^0-9]' + cast(course_id as varchar) + '[^[0-9]%'

Comment: @Sandy, that's why it's sorted in descending `course_id`. But yes, if you have that many matches it would still be a problem to get them all replaced. Could you incorporate parenthesis characters into the matches?

Comment: You can probably pad the original string with some unused character or spaces to guarantee non-digit boundaries and then trim them off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive query:

```
with courses(id,identifier) as (
    select 123, 'Alpha' union all
    select 586, 'Beta' union all
    select 309, 'Gama'
),
formulas(fid, formula) as (
  select 1, '123 and (586 or 309)' 
  union all select 2, '586 OR 309' 
),
cte(fid, lvl, formula, rformula, id, sformula) as (
  select fid, lvl, formula, rformula, f.id, replace(f.formula, f.id, c.identifier)
  from (
    select 
      fid, 1 as lvl, formula,
      substring(formula, patindex('%[0-9]%', formula)+
         patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(formula, patindex('%[0-9]%', formula)+1,len(formula))), 
         len(formula)) as rformula,
      substring(formula, patindex('%[0-9]%', formula), 
          patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(formula, patindex('%[0-9]%', formula)+1, len(formula)))
          ) as id
    from (select fid, concat(formula, ' ') as formula from formulas) f
  ) f
  join courses c on c.id = f.id

  union all

  select r.fid, r.lvl+1, r.formula,
      substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula)+patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula)+1,
         len(r.rformula))), len(r.rformula)),
      substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula), 
          patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula)+1, len(r.rformula)))),
      replace(r.sformula, substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula), 
          patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula)+1, len(r.rformula)))),
          c.identifier)
  from cte r
    join courses c on c.id = substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula), 
          patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(r.rformula, patindex('%[0-9]%', r.rformula)+1, len(r.rformula))))

  where len(r.id) > 0
)
select fid, sformula 
from (  
    select c.*, count(fid) over(partition by fid) as n from cte c
) d
where lvl = n
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/E-DJdJgu

(would be much readable if regexp_substr was available...)